# z-index not working in after class

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have pseudo element `:after` and using `position: absolute` with `z-index: 1` but this hide with parent `div`, how can I solve this?

```css
body {
  background: #2c3e50;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #0c1e30;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  height: 210px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine... [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/koof4csh/1/)

Comment: what do want its working good

Comment: I want dark div should be on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use like this:-

```css
body{background:  #2c3e50;}
.box{
 height: 200px;
 width: 130px;
 background:#0c1e30;
 margin: 10px auto;
 transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
 
 
}
.box:after{
 content: '';
 height: 210px;
 width: 120px;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 left: 0;
 top:0;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="box">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes you can use but its all depend on your requirement or your layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `z-index:1` then it will be on top of other items with lower `z-index`. If you want the `:after` to appear below the dark box then you must lower the `z-index` instead of incrementing it.

So you must set it to `z-index:-1`

```css
body {
  background: #2c3e50;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #0c1e30;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  height: 210px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to make some DOM element to go behind as in your scenario.

Comment: @htmluser Whats the point of this? Why not just put `:before` to a small size and position it at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

in the div box create a new div

```
    <div class="box"><div style="position: absolute;z-index: 2;">my text</div></div>
```